How to effectively use Actions on GitHub
I've tried to do automatic testing on GitHub but are left with this result
  Problem 1
Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^11.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[11.4.0, 11.4.1, 11.4.2, 11.4.3].
    - phpunit/phpunit[11.4.0, ..., 11.4.3] require php >=8.2 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.

    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^11.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[11.4.0, 11.4.1, 11.4.2, 11.4.3].
    - phpunit/phpunit[11.4.0, ..., 11.4.3] require php >=8.2 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.

Is there anything I can do?

This is not a GitHub workflow error. PHPUnit ^11.4 requires PHP >=8.2, but the PHP version installed during the workflow is 8.1.2.

Sure it is, in the sense that it requires running the install-php action first for that PHP version. This is how a workflow on Github actions work. @theking2: Always put the microsoft github action yaml file codes to your question, it contains way too little information for what you ask about to give a useful answer in Stackoverflows Q&A format.
